# $|G| = k < \infty$, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $|G| = n|H| \Rightarrow g^{n!} \in H$ $\forall g \in G$ where $n \in Z$

Tags: group-theory

> $|G| = k < \infty$, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $|G| = n|H|
>  \Rightarrow g^{n!} \in H$ $\forall g \in G$ where $n \in Z$

I'm not sure where to begin this proof. Here's what I know so far: 
$[G:H] = n$ 
$|a|$ $|$ $n|H|$ $\forall a \in G$

What else am I missing? Also, am I going in the right direction?

Comment: What is $g$ here? Any arbitrary member of $G$?

Comment: Yes, made an edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the index $[G:H]$ is $n$ we know that at least two of the cosets $H,gH,g^2H,...,g^nH$ are the same coset by the pigeonhole principle. So there are $0\leq i<j\leq n$ such that $g^{j-i}\in H$. But $1\leq j-i\leq n$ and hence $j-i|n!$. So $g^{n!}=(g^{j-i})^d$ when $d$ is an integer and hence $g^{n!}\in H$.

Comment: I'm confused how the fact that at least two of the cosets are the same. Here's what I know: if $[G:H]=n$ then there are $n$ cosets of $H$ that make up $G$. How do you derive that at least two of them are equal?

Comment: Because $H,gH,g^2H,...,g^nH$ are $n+1$ cosets. If we assume they are all distinct then it means there are at least $n+1$ distinct left cosets of $H$ which contradicts the fact that $[G:H]=n$.

Comment: Okay. I'm also having trouble understanding the implication. So once we know that there are at least two cosets that are equal in $G/H$ then there exists $i$ distinct cosets? Why is $i$ bounded by $j$?

Comment: What does it mean that two cosets are equal in $G/H$? $g_1H=g_2H$ if and only if $g_1^{-1}g_2\in H$. Since we know that two of the cosets $H,gH,g^2H,...g^nH$ are equal it means there are some distinct $i,j\in\{0,1,2,...n\}$ such that $g^iH=g^jH$. Without loss of generality $i<j$. And then we use the fact that $g^iH=g^jH$ means that $(g^i)^{-1}g^j=g^{j-i}\in H$.

Comment: Understood. I'm just stuck on how $1 \leq j-i \leq n$ $\Rightarrow$ $j-i | n!$. Is it because $j-1 \in [0,n]$?

Comment: By definition $n!=1\times 2\times 3\times...\times n$. So if $j-i$ is an integer in $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ then it divides $n!$.